# Detect Screen Rotation in Qt issues

Tags: c++, qt, screen-rotation

I want to do some changes on screen rotation , the code of the method that is supposed to handle such event is taken from here

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CS001437_-_Listening_for_screen_orientation_changes_in_Qt

**edit: I have a scroll area , and its getting of border on rotation how can i adjust its size?so it could fit the screen plz check the event handler below** 
this my whole code :

```
//FORM1.CPP
#include "form1.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include <QResizeEvent>



Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form1::~Form1()
{
    delete ui;
}

//the method that is supposed to handle such event
void Form1::resizeEvent (QResizeEvent* event)
{
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    ui->textBrowser->setText("karim");
}
```

I got this error:

```
\Users\user\Desktop\karim\Qt\Project\form1.cpp:31: error: 'QMyWidget' has not been declared
```

Please note that I didn't do anything else this is my whole code ...
Can you please tell me whats wrong or what am not getting ?

**Please be specific I would appreciate that ...**

Comment: You might need to pick up a basic C++ book. You're pasting code without understanding it. In particular, it seems that you don't understand what the left and right side of `QMyWidget::resizeEvent` refer to.

Comment: i am sorry i wasnt thinking , please check my edit .. i have onther issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any reference to your `QMyWidget` class other than the below line. May be I'm missing something. But if you have defined your `QMyWidget` class elsewhere, you atleast need to include the header.

```
void QMyWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    ui->labelk->setText("blabla");
}
```

May be you meant this instead of the above:

```
void Form1::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    ui->labelk->setText("blabla");
}
```

Update to the comment: You can try doing this.

```
void Form1::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    // call the base class for the default behavior
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    // Add your custom changes here
    ui->labelk->setText("blabla");
}
```

Comment: thank you Purnima , i just got this other issue now.
I have a scroll area inside the form i want it to adjust size on screen rotation so it could fit and nothing go off border , any idea how this could be done ?

Comment: Try calling the base class `QWidget::resizeEvent()` in your custom implementation. Maybe that should take care of scroll area going out of bounds. `void Form1::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event){QWidget::resizeEvent(event);//your custom code goes here   ui->labelk->setText("blabla");}`

Comment: i would appreciate if u can edit ur answer to show me how this thing could be done

Comment: well i did what u told me and it did nothing ... the scroll area is still getting of border

Comment: When you provide custom implementation of `QWidget::resizeEvent()`, you need to take care of the layout as well. So I guess you need to get the new dimensions using `QWidget::size` and try to set the scrollarea widget size accordingly. That might help.

Comment: i would appreciate if u can edit ur answer to show me how this thing could be done , again am sorry but am new to qt

Comment: @Karim: I myself have never gone into those details but searching for similar problems gave me this [thread about resize event handling](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-09/thread00211-0.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You must create slot

```
connect(qApp->desktop(), SIGNAL(resized(int)), this, SLOT(onResized(int)));
```

and implement it like:

```
void Widget::onResized(int)
{
    QDesktopWidget* screen = qApp->desktop();   
    QSize displaySize;
    if (screen) {
        displaySize = screen->screenGeometry().size();
        if (displaySize != this->size()) {
            this->resize(displaySize);
        }
    }
}
```